# Print rows whose last field is negative

Tags: awk

The last column of my file contains both negative and positive numbers:

```
a, b, -1
c, d, 2
e, f, -3
```

I need to extract the lines whose last field contains a negative number.  Currently, I am using the following:

```
awk '/-/{print}' in.csv>out.csv
```

The above fails if '-' appears in other columns. I wonder if there is a way to test the last field in each row to see if they are negative and then extract the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell awk to do...

```
awk -F, '$NF < 0' file
```

This sets the field separator to the comma (it looks like this is what you need) and then checks if `$NF` is lower than 0. And what is `$NF`? The last field, since `NF` contains the number of fields and `$i` points to the field number `i`.

The line is then printed, because a True condition triggers the default `awk` action, consisting in printing the current record.